# How to don't remove the break when I use twocolumn after onecolumn?

Tags: two-column, columns, author

I have a problem; when I add \twocolumn after \onecolumn, my page is breaked :

```
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}  
        ...
        \begin{document}
    %
    \author{123 \and
            456 \and
            789
    }
    \institute{AAAAAA \at
                  BBBBB \\}
    %
\onecolumn
            \maketitle
            \begin{abstract}
              ...
            \end{abstract}

\twocolumn 
        \end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to change between onecolumn and twocolumn text without a page break consider the `multicol` package.

Comment: you can use the optional argument of `\twocolumn` to add text that spans over both columns

Answer (score 1):

`\twocolumn` always starts a new page but has an optional argument that allows the specification of text that spans the columns.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}  
\title{Zzzz the title zzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzzz}
\date{today}
\journalname{zz}
        \begin{document}
    %
    \author{123 \and
            456 \and
            789
    }
    \institute{AAAAAA \at
                  BBBBB \\}
    %
\twocolumn[
            \maketitle
            \begin{abstract}
             Abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract.
             Abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract.
             Abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract.
             Abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract.
             Abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract.
             Abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract.
             Abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract.
            \end{abstract}
]

 \def \texta{One two three four five six seven eight nine ten. }
\def\textb{\texta\texta\texta\texta\texta\texta\texta}
\textb

\textb\textb\textb\textb

Red blue yellow \texta\textb\textb
        \end{document}
```